# `<<': invalid date (ArgumentError) in hash

Tags: ruby

Here's my code:

```
item = []
today = Date.today

dates = {"3 years" => today << 12*3, "2 years" => today << 12*2,
"1.5 years" => today <<  12*1.5,"1 year" => today << 12, "6 months" => today << 6,
"3 months" => today << 3, "today" => today}
```

I'm getting this error `` `<<': invalid date (ArgumentError) `` on the line that starts with `dates...` every time I run it.

What's wrong? `today` should be a valid date, and I tried putting parenthesis around the multiplication, and around the value fields, but still that error. When I tried it in irb, it worked fine. Date is required at the top of the file.

Comment: Works just fine in IRB 1.9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"1.5 years" => today <<  12*1.5
```

This one is the culprit. Replace it by `"1.5 years" => today <<  18` , because the `<<` method is apparently not capable of handling floats (in 1.9.3).

Comment: Yes it does.

`{"1.5 years" => Date.today << 12*1.5}`

` => {"1.5 years"=>#<Date: 2011-05-27 ((2455709j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}`

Comment: Yup, this was it for me. Not sure why it works for others but not me, but that's the line that threw the error when I separated the statement. No more error after changing `12*1.5` to `18`.

Answer (score 0):

did you forget to `require 'date'`?

seems to work well on all versions.

#### [Here is a proof](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=invalid-date-argumenterror-in-hash.rb&versions=%2a&run=true)

Comment: Yes, I required date at the top of the file.